# Reading current cardboard device parameters of loaded profile

Tags: android, google-cardboard

When I scan a QR code to read a cardboard device parameters using cardboard app. It stores data in a file at

```
/sdcard/cardboard/current_device_para
```

When I open current_device_para using a text viewer, I see some encoded data. How can I decode or read it in human readable format. I do not know why cardboard sdk for android do not provides a mechanism to get viewer profile information directly from SDK and why they are encoding this data. Please share if you have any information regarding this. I need to read current loaded data in one of my C++ based game where I am implementing my own distortion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device parameters are exposed via CardboardView's [getCardboardDeviceParams](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/CardboardView.html#public-methods_2) function.